# Check Binary Compatibility of Machines

Tags: linux

I have two Linux OS flavor machines one is `CentOS-5.4` and one is `Amazon Linux`. I need to check if the two machines are binary compatible or not

For binary compatibility I need to check the following:

- Both machines must use two's-complement integer arithmetic
- Both machines must use IEEE floating-point format or else the tables must contain no floating-point columns (FLOAT or DOUBLE)

How can I check this?

Comment: run it on both platforms?